# How do I migrate my legacy FCM HTTP requests to HTTP V1?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-security

I received an email from Google informing me that I need to migrate my Android app that uses FCM for client-to-client communication by early May 2022 to the more secure V1 protocol, along with a link to instructions. Following the link, I modified my server endpoint but am not sure where to get the authorization token:

```
        final String serverKey = "Authorization: Bearer <valid Oauth 2.0 token>";
```

The [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1#java) () go on to say the following:

```
Depending on the details of your server environment, use a combination of these strategies to authorize server requests to Firebase services:

Google Application Default Credentials (ADC)
A service account JSON file
A short-lived OAuth 2.0 access token derived from a service account
```

At first glance, it looked like I needed to authenticate via ADC, but after more reading, it seems that ADC is used if I have my own code running on a Google server. I don't; I'm just pushing notifications to the user. So how should I proceed?

Comment: It reads "depending on the details of your server environment", which you seem to ignore... while the question even already kind of contains the answer.

Comment: @MartinZeitler "Kind of" isn't an answer. What do they mean by my "server environment"? Are they assuming my app is talking to some code I've written that runs on the backend?

Comment: By ADC they likely mean environmental variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`, which is referencing a service-account configuration JSON, by which an OAuth 2.0 token can be obtained by REST API call, to be used for subsequent API calls. This does not depend on any server, eg. runs in local unit tests, while being able to present the service account's private key. However, for Android one cannot package this file. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1#use-credentials-to-mint-access-tokens

Answer (score -2):

The following doc give you clear steps to migrate to HTTP V1.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1

Comment: Thanks, but I already know about that page. It left me with more questions than it answered.

Comment: @FractalBob did you eventually find a solution on how to perform the migration?

Comment: @Pandruz No, I finally gave up.

Comment: try this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oNoRw69ro2k&ab_channel=NativeNotify